# Show gallery images in one row

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

**According to my previous closed question
[Display images in one row, hide all others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737126/display-images-in-one-row-hide-all-others)**

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">

    <?php
    $images = get_field( 'galeria' );

    if ( $images ) :
        foreach ( $images as $image ) : ?>

                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" data-fancybox="gallery">
                         <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" class="d-block mx-auto">
                    </a>
                    <p><?php echo $image['caption']; ?></p>
                </div>

        <?php endforeach; 
    endif; ?>

    </div>                      
</div>
```

**I'm working on custom Wordpress theme and have standard gallery lightbox:**
[image]

**My client want to edit gallery to this form:**
[image]

**All items should be displayed in one row, three colums and the last window should display count of remaining items in gallery, and after click on it display them...(I don't know if in grid or something elses) I really have no idea how to do this. I found nothing on entire web. Help me with some tips and don't close this question!**

Comment: You are trying to develop a carousel / slide show? There many online examples of single slide views that could be expanded to as many as you want. - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should not be reopening/reasking questions just because they are closed, especially if you're not going to provide more details. That's a good way to build a bad rapport.

That said, what you want is fairly simple. Just count the items in your `$images` array. If it exceeds 2, add a fake item that has a count of "total images - 2". Add a JavaScript onclick event to it that will remove the fake item, and show the following hidden items. Just use a `hidden` class on any element after the third. That's the most basic way to achieve what you're looking for. You can also load them in dynamically via ajax, fancy animations, etc. But that's beyond the scope of this question.

## PHP:

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
    <?php
        if( $images = get_field( 'galeria' ) ){
            for( $i = 0, $n = count($images); $i < $n; $i++ ){ ?>
                <?php if( $i == 2 ){ ?>
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" onclick="showRemainingImages(this,event);">
                        <?php
                            $remaining = $n - 2;
                            echo "+{$remaining} Images";
                        ?>
                        <p><?php echo $image['caption']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 <?php echo ($i>1)?'hidden':''; ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" data-fancybox="gallery">
                             <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" class="d-block mx-auto">
                        </a>
                    <p><?php echo $image['caption']; ?></p>
                </div>
            <?php }
        }
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

## JS:

```
<script>
    function showRemainingImages(el,e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var container = el.closest('.container');
        var hidden    = container.querySelectorAll('.hidden');

        if( hidden.length > 0 ){
            hidden.forEach(function(col){
                col.classList.remove('hidden');
            });
        }

        el.remove();
    }
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
    .hidden { display: none; }
</style>
```

Here's a quick codepen I mocked up. Note the HTML structure is a bit different, I have a custom grid on hand, but you should be able to get the idea from it. https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/zYxLBZG